# Deploying an MVC in Appharbor. I am getting an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appharbor

This is the error: Where can i find this error came from ?

> Primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
>        2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2041,5):
>
> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors.
>
> [D:\temp\q11j21w4.40a\input\LebaneseCarParts\LebaneseCarParts.csproj]
>                    For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".

Comment: sounds like you didn't deploy a DLL for MySQL

Comment: i am not using MySQL.. where can i found this "MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, " to remove  everything related to MySql

Comment: I don't know where your code references it, perhaps you have an unnecessary project reference. You'll have to look at your code and find it.